# Reorganising the order of a conditionnaly convergent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

I was reading [this article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) about reorganizing the order of summation of a series. I dont understand why if we reorganise the series

$0=1-1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots$

By taking first $p$ positive numbers of the series and then $q$ negative ones we get $ln(p/q)$ as result.

Comment: What is the partial sum of the first $k\cdot (p+q)$ numbers under that rearrangement?

Comment: $\frac{1}{kq+1}+\ldots +\frac{1}{kp}$?

Comment: If $q < p$ (or $q \leqslant p$, if we take the convention that what you wrote then means $0$). Generally, we can write it as $$\sum_{n = 1}^{kp} \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n = 1}^{kq} \frac{1}{n}\,.$$ You can see that that tends to $\log \frac{p}{q}$, I think. And then it remains to see that since the terms tend to $0$ and the distance between the indices of these partial sums is bounded, the full series converges.

Comment: I am not sure how to show this is $log(p/q)$. We don't have that the first sum goes to $log(p)$ and the second sum goes to $log(q)$

Comment: We have $$\sum_{n = 1}^m \frac{1}{n} = \log m + \gamma + O(1/m)$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant. But the value of the constant is irrelevant, since we subtract the sums for $m = kp$ and for $m = kq$. We obtain $$\sum_{n = 1}^{kp} \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n = 1}^{kq} \frac{1}{n} = \log (kp) - \log (kq) + O(1/k) = \log \frac{kp}{kq} + O(1/k) = \log \frac{p}{q} + O(1/k)\,.$$

Comment: I see. How do you get the $O(1/m)$? I.e. why $H_m -log(m) -\lim_{m\to\infty}(H_m-log(m)) = O(1/m)?$ In general $x_m-y_m-\lim_{m\to \infty}(x_n-y_n)$ can be something else than $O(1/m)$ no?

Comment: Yes, in general it can be something different. There are lots of ways to prove the $O(1/m)$ error term here (probably one or two on the wikipedia page for harmonic numbers). Let's sketch a fairly general and useful one. Let $f$ be a (weakly) monotonically decreasing positive function with $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. Then $$L_f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Biggl(\int_1^n f(x)\,dx - \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k)\Biggr)$$ exists, and $$\Biggl\lvert \int_1^n f(x)\,dx - \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k) - L_f\Biggr\rvert = O(f(n))\,.$$ For the proof, fix $n$, pick $m > n$, and look at

Comment: $$\int_n^m f(x)\,dx - \sum_{k = n+1}^m f(k) = \sum_{k = n+1}^m \biggl(\int_{k-1}^k f(x)\,dx - f(k)\biggr) = \sum_{k = n+1}^m \int_{k-1}^k \bigl(f(x) - f(k)\bigr)\,dx\,.$$ On the right, we always have $0 \leqslant f(x) - f(k) \leqslant f(k-1) - f(k)$ by monotonicity, and thus the whole thing is sandwiched between $0$ and $$\sum_{k = n+1}^m \bigl(f(k-1) - f(k)\bigr) = f(n) - f(m)\,.$$ Now take limits to finish the proof. Here, we have $f(x) = 1/x$.